# Clusplot of dissimilarity matrix, how to list components?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, visualization, k-means, pca

First off, I apologize if this is a stupid question. I am a medical doctor and never studied mathematics/statistics, so all I know is self-taught over the course of my PhD.

To analyze my data I'm using a daisy() produced dissimilarity matrix as source for kmeans() clustering and visualising the result with clusplot(). The clusplot provides information about how much point variability the two visualised components provide taken together, but not separately. Is there a way to show % of point variability for each component separately?

Do I undestand correctly, that the daisy output does not have principal components per se, but the clusplot pretty much runs PCA on it and uses the first two components? If so, can it list all the components with % of explained variability?

Thanks a lot!

Example code:

```
gower_dist <- daisy(data, metric = "gower")
fit <- kmeans(gower_dist, 3, nstart = 20)
attr(gower_dist,"Labels")=data[,5]
clusplot(as.matrix(gower_dist), diss=TRUE, fit$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=FALSE, labels=3, lines=0, plotchar=FALSE, stand=TRUE, span=TRUE)
```

Comment: Did you look at the source code of clusplot? Library recommendations are off-topic here. Try to solve things by writing actual code.

Comment: No, I have not looked at the source code of clusplot, and it's very likely I wouldn't understand it. I see people recommending packages and libraries frequently in the various answers... I am trying to solve things, but when I don't know, I ask. Not sure why you would spend time criticising my question without actually saying anything constructive or related to the topic at all.